# can Dapper implement multiple delete insert or update as QueryMultiple?

Tags: dapper

I have seen QueryMultiple from Dapper official doc as below, It is convenient!

```
     var sql = @"
select * from Customers where CustomerId = @id
select * from Orders where CustomerId = @id
select * from Returns where CustomerId = @id";

using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, new {id=selectedId}))
{
   var customer = multi.Read<Customer>().Single();
   var orders = multi.Read<Order>().ToList();
   var returns = multi.Read<Return>().ToList();
   ...
}
```

Now, when I delete record from Parent-table,I want to delete related record from  Child-table. 
can Dapper fit it? It looks that as below.

```
 var sql = @"delete from tb_role where roleid=@ID
                            delete from tb_rolepermission where roleid=@ID
                            delete from tb_userrole where roleid=@ID
        ";
        var param = new { ID=id };

 connection.EXECUTEMultiple(sql, param)..........
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: As BK. observes, *any* SQL command can perform multiple operations - the only significance in `QueryMultiple` is how it processes the results grid to get the data out. You do not need to change anything to execute your multi-statement command - just `Execute(sql, param)` should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can can simply call connection.Execute and it already allows multiple commands like you are trying to do, the same as ExecuteQuery allows on SqlCommand, which is all Dapper is calling anyways.

Comment: BK,thank you for reply. is it alternative of dapper transaction? what is the difference between them? and which is better about performance? Thanks again.

Comment: @Kevin can you clarify that question? It seems to be about transactions... you can indeed use transactions with dapper, but it won't do it automatically (there is a parameter for that). Re "better" / "performance" - what 2 (or more) things are we comparing here?

Comment: @Marc Gravell  sorry for unclear question! when meeting with multiple SQL implementation plan. which function will be given priority to ? 
connection.Execute(sql, param) or connection.Execute(string sql, dynamic param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null)

Comment: @Kevin that is the same method. The only difference is that in one of them you've specified the parameters. There is no difference just from adding extra null parameters. Unless you're using the c# 3 build, in which case it is a different method, but *still* won't have any performance difference.

Comment: any full sample code using it? and get the number of affected registers ? I have ***9 updates statements***